# How can I get the lblmessage to display only if Confirm button is clicked before Calculate button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Confirm.aspx.cs" Inherits="XEx04Quotation.Confirm" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Confirm quotation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" class="form-horizontal">

        <main class="container">

            <h1 class="jumbotron">Quotation confirmation</h1>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Sales price</label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblSalesPrice" runat="server" CssClass="col-sm-3 bold"></asp:Label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Discount amount</label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblDiscountAmount" runat="server" CssClass="col-sm-3 bold"></asp:Label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Total price</label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTotalPrice" runat="server" CssClass="col-sm-3 bold"></asp:Label>
            </div> 

            <div class="row">
                <h3 class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">Send confirmation to</h3>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName" 
                        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required" CssClass="text-danger"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </div>  
            </div>  
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email address</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" 
                        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required" CssClass="text-danger"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </div>  
            </div>  

            <%-- Quotation and Return buttons --%>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                    <%-- buttons go here --%>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Send Quotation"  CssClass="btn btn-primary"/>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Return" CssClass="btn btn-primary" PostBackUrl="~/Default.aspx" CausesValidation="false"/>
                </div>
            </div> 
            
            <%-- message label --%>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-11">
                    <%-- message label goes here --%>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblmessage" runat="server" Text="Click the Send Quotation button to send the quotation via email" CssClass="text-info"></asp:Label>
                </div>
            </div>

        </main>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace XEx04Quotation
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UnobtrusiveValidationMode = UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;
        }

        protected void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsValid)
            {
                decimal salesPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSalesPrice.Text);

                // save the salesPrice into a session state variable 
                Session["SalesPrice"] = salesPrice;


                decimal discountPercent = Convert.ToDecimal(txtDiscountPercent.Text) / 100;

    
                decimal discountAmount = salesPrice * discountPercent;

                // save the discountAmount into a session state variable
                Session["Discount"] = discountAmount;

                
                decimal totalPrice = salesPrice - discountAmount;

                // save the totalPrice into a session state variable

                Session["TotalPrice"] = totalPrice;

                lblDiscountAmount.Text = discountAmount.ToString("c");
                lblTotalPrice.Text = totalPrice.ToString("c");
            }   
        }

        protected void Button1_Confirm(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             if(Session["SalesPrice"] != null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Confirm.aspx");
            }
            else 
            {
                // This is the part I am concerned about
                lblmessage2.Text = "Click the Calculate button before you click confirm";
            }
            


        }
    }
}
```

Hello Everyone,

I am building multi-web application pages using the Default.aspx, Default.aspx.cs and Confirm.aspx and Confirm.aspx.cs. The problem that I am having is that when I click "Confirm" before clicking "Calculate," the event handler displays the "Click the Calculate button before the confirm"  at the bottom of the page. It does that even if the Calculate button is clicked before the Confirm and also displays again when I reload the page. **How can I get this to only display if the session state value of SalesPrice is null? Otherwise, it will redirect to the confirm page.** Here is Default.aspx.cs and other file:

Comment: only define your code *not working* instead of whole application.

Comment: @Asif.Ali You only want me to include the files Confirm.aspx and Confirm.aspx.cs?

Comment: @Asif.Ali Do you see the update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do one thing. If you want to get the total calculation first, then disable the confirm button and clicking on the calculate button will enable the button as follows:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Enabled="false" />

protected void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button1.Enabled = True;

   if(Session["TotalPrice"] != null)
   {
       lblMsg.Text = "Please click here to see total calculation";
   }
}

protected void Button1_Confirm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(Session["SalesPrice"] != null)
   {
       Response.Redirect("Confirm.aspx");
   }
}
```

**Note**: Please follow the naming convention for the event names. **Button1** To **btnConfirm**.

**Update 1** - Try the below tested code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCalculate" runat="server" Text="Calculate" OnClick="btnCalculate_Click" />

<asp:Button ID="btnConfirm" runat="server" Text="Confirm" OnClick="btnConfirm_Click" />

<asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>


private int buttonWasClicked = 0; //Kept a variable type of int and with a default value 0

protected void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   buttonWasClicked = 1; //If clicked, then 1
   Session["value"] = Convert.ToInt32(buttonWasClicked); //Then kept in session

   lblMsg.Text = "Total Price - 10,000";
}

protected void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Session["value"] != null) //If session not null, then redirect page
   {
      Response.Redirect("CustomerDetails.aspx");
      Session["value"] = null; //Clears the session
   }
   else
   {
      lblMsg.Text = "Click the calculate button first";
   }
}
```

Comment: -How will I put my message "Click the Calculate button before the confirm"  that I want within of the btnCalculate_Click() event handler?

Comment: What message do you want to put?

Comment: "Click the Calculate button before the confirm."

Comment: I've provided a sample with `Label`. I guess, you can show it in the calculate button if `Session['TotalPrice']` not null by default.

Comment: @AT-2017-Are you there? I appreciate your contribution in helping me solve my problem, but I just want to know if you show where my message can be inserted at.

Comment: @ AT-2017 Is there a way that I can still write the message in the Button1_Confirm() event handler so it's fired when user clicks on the confirm button before the calculate?

Comment: I am not sure if the above works but I've updated a sample. Try @dorakta.

Comment: @AT-2017-But I still don't see my message in the update code anywhere.

Comment: Never mind. Have you taken a label in the front-end with the ID `lblMsg`?

Comment: @AT-2017-Do you think you can just use my existing code and show me how I can make the if/else statements work in my favor, please?

Comment: Updated @dorakta. You can use it now as expected.